# Чем отличается союзное слово от местоименного наречия?

Tags: морфология

Чем отличается союзное слово от местоименного наречия?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Союзные слова - это относительные местоимения (кто, что, какой, чей, который) и местоименные наречия (где, куда, когда, откуда, почему, зачем, как), служащие для связи главной и придаточной частей в сложноподчиненном предложении.

Термин "местоименные наречия" обозначает лексико-семантическую принадлежность слов. А термин "союзные слова" применяется как обозначение синтаксической функции средства связи, которую выполняют местоименные наречия (они могут быть членами предложения).

Comment: Получается,в таком предложении, как "Он нашел человека, который до недавнего времени считался пропащим",слово "который" является союзным словом?Спасибо :)